# Logarithm evaluation for a beginner

Tags: logarithms

I need to evaluate this $e^{2\ln(e+3)}.$

I am new to Logarithms so I'm struggling with this. I'm not sure from where to start.

Comment: I'd start by revising the definition of logarithm and formulas.

Comment: I started to flag this q for closure

Comment: $e^{2ln(e+3)} = e^{ln(e+3)^2} = (e+3)^2$ you may had done search online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e^{2\ln(e+3)}$ can be written as $e^{\ln(e+3)^2}$(Because of the property of Logarithms). Now, if you have something in the form of $e^{\ln x}$ then it is equal to $x$($e$ and $\ln$ cancel out). So $e^{\ln(e+3)^2}$ becomes $(e + 3)^2$ which is your answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @lone student, its actually correct... Idk why it seems wrong to you. I used property of Logarithms to solve it. And after your comment, I even checked it on SymboLab and WolframAlpha, Here are the links : https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/e%5E%7B2ln%5Cleft(e%2B3%5Cright)%7D and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7B2ln%28e%2B3%29%7D. Check these if you don't believe

Comment: No.Your Wolfy input is different, than what you did in your answer.. Your correct input must be $$e^{\ln(e+3)^2}$$

Comment: @lone student, The question actually asks us to evaluate $e^{2\ln(e+3)}$. So, the answer is $(e+3)^2$

Comment: In your answer you showed  that, $$e^{\ln(e+3)^2}=e^{2\ln(e+3)}$$ But this is not correct.

Comment: $e^{\ln(e+3)^2}$ equals $e^{2\ln(e+3)}$ because of the property of Logarithms so then what is the problem with that. I even entered the input you recommended and still it shows the same answer. Here is the link : https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/e%5E%7Bln%5Cleft(e%2B3%5Cright)%5E2%7D%5E%7B%20%7D

Comment: Your input is completely incorrect. Look carefully your input.

Comment: Please check: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7B%5Cln%28e%2B3%29%5E2%7D%3De%5E%7B2%5Cln%28e%2B3%29%7D

Comment: wolframalpha is taking the input as $e^{\ln^2(e+3)}$ and not $e^{\ln(e+3)^2}$

Comment: These are equal $$\ln^2(e+3)=(\ln (e+3))^2$$

Comment: The answer is $(e+3)^2$. But, your notations are incorrect.

Comment: There is no problem. I will not say anything new.  You can find it anywhere. Maybe you confused $${(5^2)}^3=25^3, 5^{2^3}=5^8$$ We have $$\left(e^{\ln(e+3)}\right)^2=e^{2\ln(e+3)}$$

Comment: @lonestudent I don't see a problem in the given answer. You are just debating over the syntax of the WolfRam Alpha. He just missed an additional bracket around (e+3) therefore got a different rendering of the equation. Therefore it is incorrect to downvote just because of that. On the contrary your understanding of logs might require some brushing. Refer to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7B2%5Cln%28e%2B3%29%7D+%3D+e%5E%7Bln%28%28e%2B3%29%5E2%29%7D+%3D+%28e%5E%7Bln%28e%2B3%29%7D%29%5E2

Comment: @Favonius please check comments carefully. I gave to OP an example.